# Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27'

Tags: node.js, linux, compilation, glibc, node-gyp

I am building my node module (using N-API) both for Mac (10.9+) and Linux (Ubuntu 18). When I am deploying my module to remote machine (to Heroku), I am getting:

```
Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/addons/Release-linux/module.node)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:717:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    (...)
```

Running `ldd --version` on both machines:

```
~ $ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27
```

and:

```
~ $ ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
libm.so.6 (...)
```

Also, I am not sure why linking to `libm` is necessary, as I am not using `#include <math.h>` within my code (compiler is adding `libm` implicitly?).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to deploy into an operation system that is compatible with your build environment.  Usually, this means to use the same distribution version.  In some cases, it is also possible to deploy on a newer version of the same distribution.

Your version of Ubuntu uses glibc 2.27.  Your deployment target uses something earlier, presumably either [Heroku-16](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-16-stack) or [Cedar-14](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-stack), since you said you are trying to deploy on Heroku.  You either have to rebuild your software in a matching build environment (for example, using [`pbuilder`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pbuilder.8.html), or using a virtual machine), or deploy into something that is compatible with your version of Ubuntu (presumably, [Heroku-18](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack)).

Comment: Interesting. I've downloaded the `heroku-18` docker image (this is my stack on Heroku), compiled the module under that stack, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Quoting: "Your deployment target uses something earlier, presumably either Heroku-16 or Cedar-14" - my deployment target is `heroku-18`, and `ldd --version` says there is a `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27`

Comment: libm from glibc 2.27 definitely has `GLIBC_2.27` symbol versions, so either the Heroku image is corrupted, or you are not deploying with the right configuration (so that you end up with something else). Perhaps this is a case for Heroku customer support?

Comment: Looks like the Heroku image was corrupted, the module works when built with `heroku-16`